# Get data from array in Controller

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have function in my Contoller

```
public function dataCountry()
    {
        $this->country = array(
            1 =>    'Serbia',
            2 =>    'USA',
            3 =>    'Croatia',
            4 =>    'Russia',
            5 =>    'China'
        );
    }
```

Also at start class i have

```
$this->country = array();
```

So i have sql query where i am calling some info from database. I have result as

```
$item->country
```

Where i get result like this:

```
[country] => 1,4
```

So how can i change or effect that to replace and have "," between in result. I will do this before do view, i will change $item->country = "*THAT REPLACE FROM COUNTRY*". But i don't know how to do that.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: doesn't your result already have a comma? Or if you wanted to replace the comma, replace it with what?

Comment: Yes, my result already have a comma, like. [country] => 7,9,17. So i just want to replace that number with string. But don't know how to replace. Or there is better way to use country to display. Sometimes there is only one, but sometimes there is more than one.

Comment: Oh, yes, let me show something, tell me if it works.

Comment: I'll wait for that. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public function dataCountry()
{
    $this->country = array(
        1 =>    'Serbia',
        2 =>    'USA',
        3 =>    'Croatia',
        4 =>    'Russia',
        5 =>    'China'
    );

    //after database query you end up with
    $item->country = "1,4";

    $item->country = explode(",", $item->country);

    for($i=0; $i < count($item->country); $i++) {
        $index = $item->country[$i];

        if( !empty($this->country[$index]) ) {
            $item->country[$i] = $this->country[$index];
        }
    }

    $item->country = implode(",", $item->country);

    echo $item->country;
    // Should output: Serbia,Russia
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but can you tell me also how to implement this in multiple array like [link](https://i.imgur.com/z7eOlVP.png) where if i have 2 country, i can use and ID and Flag and Country name. I have array(2, 'Argentina', 'argentina.png'), in already array. Is this easy? I'm trying sometning but not working. :D thank you again.

Comment: @PooX Sure, instead of `if( !empty($this->country[$index]) ) {` you would have a `foreach()` that goes through all the top level indexes of the array and then you could check if the value is in the sub-array using `$someItem[0]` if we called the variable in the foreach `$someItem`. It's best to ask this in  a new question, it will be much easier to communicate in code.

Comment: Thanks, i open new question there: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230543/get-data-from-multiple-array-in-controller)