# Get data from multiple array in Controller

Tags: php, arrays

I have country list in array with multiple array, like:

```
public static function listCountries()
    {
        $this->country = array(
            array(1, 'SAD', 'sad.png'),
            array(2, 'Argentina', 'argentina.png'),
            array(3, 'Australija', 'australija.png'),
            array(4, 'Novi Zenland', 'noviz.png'),
            array(5, 'Belgija', 'belg.png'),
            array(6, 'Nizozemska', 'nizozemska.png')
        );
    }
```

But when i do foreach for array, i'm getting this:

```
//From DB
    $item->country = "1,4";

    $item->country = explode(",", $item->country);

    for($i=0; $i < count($item->country); $i++) {
        $index = $item->country[$i];

        if( !empty($this->country[$index]) ) {
            $item->country[$i] = $this->country[$index];
        }
    }

    $item->country = implode(",", $item->country);

    echo $item->country;
```

But i'm getting something like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 5
    1 => "Belgija"
    2 => "belg.png"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => "Argentina"
    2 => "argentina.png"
  ]
]
```

1 = SAD, 4 = Novi Zenland, not Belgija and Argentina
There is no good country, also no data what i want. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `foreach` loop to go through the other array and swap the string if the number matches:

```
$item->country = "1,4";

$item->country = explode(",", $item->country);

for($i=0; $i < count($item->country); $i++) {
    $index = $item->country[$i];

    foreach($this->country as $c) {
        if($c[0] == $index) {
            $item->country[$i] = $c[1];   // or $item->country[$i] = $c; if you want all three items
            break;
        }
    }
}

$item->country = implode(",", $item->country);

echo $item->country;
// Should output: SAD,Novi Zenland
```

Comment: I did it with small changes, there where is $item['country'][$i] i change this to $item->country[$i]. Can you edit post so i can vote for Answer? Thank you for all, Ivan :)

Answer (score 0):

The indexes in arrays are `0-based`, which means that:

```
$index = $item->country[$i];
```

Has to become

```
$index = $item->country[$i - 1];
```

To correlate with the country ids. Otherwise, it is always one off. This is assuming that the ids are always ordered from least to greatest, and all ids are a continuous range.